# Printing using loop

Tags: c, loops, printf

The variable I'm using is "rightnumber" I just can't seem to figure out why this program isn't working. Expected Output image provided.

```
const int limit = 5;

int main() {
    int row, spacing, leftnumber, rightnumber = 1;
    for (row = 1; row < limit + 1; row++) {
        for (spacing = 1; spacing < limit - row + 1; spacing++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (leftnumber = 1; leftnumber < row + 1; leftnumber++) {
            printf("%d", leftnumber);
        }
        for (rightnumber = row; rightnumber == 0; rightnumber -= 1) {
            printf("%d", rightnumber);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
    1
   12
  123
 1234
12345
```

My expected output:

```
    1
   232
  34543
 4567654
567898765
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys! Never thought of using 2 loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print your desired Output, you can try to identify the pattern in the output and figure it out yourself.

```
#include<stdio.h>
const int limit = 5;
int main()
{
    int row, spacing, leftnumber,rightnumber=1;
    int last;
    for(row=1;row<limit+1;row++)
    {
        for(spacing=1;spacing<limit-row+1;spacing++)
        {
            printf(" ");

        }
        for(leftnumber=row;leftnumber<row+1;leftnumber++)
            {
                printf("%d",leftnumber);
            }
        for(rightnumber=row+1; rightnumber<2*row; rightnumber+=1)
        {
            printf("%d",rightnumber);
        }
        for(last=rightnumber-2; last >= row && last > 0; last--){
            printf("%d",last);
        }




        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I condensed Rohit's answer to one loop. Hope this helps anyone who sees this thread in the future.

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int limit = 5;
int main()
{
    int row, spacing, leftnumber,rightnumber,a;
    for(row=1;row<limit+1;row++)
    {
        for(spacing=1;spacing<limit-row+1;spacing++)
        {
            printf(" ");

        }
        for(leftnumber=1;leftnumber<row+1;leftnumber++)
            {
                printf("%d",leftnumber);
            }
        for(rightnumber=row-1;rightnumber>0;rightnumber--)
        {
            printf("%d",rightnumber);
        }


        printf("\n");
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int n, c, d, num = 1, space;
printf("Enter a number\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
space = n - 1;
for ( d = 1 ; d <= n ; d++ )
{
num = d;
for ( c = 1 ; c <= space ; c++ )
printf(" ");
space--;
for ( c = 1 ; c <= d ; c++ )
{
printf("%d", num);
num++;
}
num--;
num--;
for ( c = 1 ; c < d ; c++)
{
printf("%d", num);
num--;
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please, explain your code to the user who asked the question. You changed the variables' names, it is really hard to understand it.